# Failed login to MSSQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to log into a local SQL database, but I keep getting an error about 'Login Failed'. This is the first time that I have tried to connect to a MS SQL server... normally I use MySQL. So, I am not even sure if I am doing this correctly.

Here is my connection code:

```
function dbConnection()
{
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db = 'my_db';
    $user = 'dbuser';
    $pass = "my_pw";

    $serverName = "tcp:$host,1443";
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database"=>$db,
        "Uid"=>$user, 
        "PWD"=>$pass
    );

    $connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    if (!$connection) print_r(sqlsrv_errors());

    return $connection;
}

print_r(dbConnection());
```

Everytime I try this, I get:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
> user 'dbuser'.

The username and password are correct, and the permission are set correctly. The port is correct, too. I can log into SSMS just fine, but not through PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to have two instances of SQL Server running on the same machine?

Comment: (1) if your mssql server instance is say sqlexpress, please use $serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; or if the port is 1443, then $serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress, 1443" -- please note that default mssql server port is 1433. I don't think `tcp:` is needed in both cases (2) I don't know whether Uid is ok but normally it is UID.

Comment: @KenLee The 'Uid' and 'tcp:' are fine. The issue was not adding the sql express. As soon as I did that, it worked. Please submit an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your mssql server instance is say sqlexpress..

Please use

```
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress";
```

or if the port is 1443, then

```
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress, 1443"
```